# how to each row in gridview makes a hyperlink to another action in asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I am a beginner in asp.net. The problem is silly for experts I think. 
The problem is I have a student table in mysql. student table has a column named "batch". When user search for a batch then the students names from that batch comes to a gridview table.

Now i a want to make link for every column so that if user click a row of table,then  the full profile of that student shows in a new page.

How can I make the rows as Hyperlink?

Comment: Have you written any code? Or just imagining about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is too broad.

> want to make link for every column so that if user click a row of
>   table,then the full profile of that student shows in a new page

Redirecting user to a **new page** just by **single clicking** on a row is not user friendly.

Instead, you can create a hyperlink in a cell. When a user clicks on a link, then redirect the user to details page.

*You can use either [HyperLinkField or TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a link in GridView. For example -*

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField
            DataNavigateUrlFields="Batch"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Details.aspx?id={0}"
            DataTextField="Batch"
            DataTextFormatString="{0}">
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1"
                    NavigateUrl='~/Details.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Batch") %>'>
                    <%# Eval("Batch") %>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

***FYI:*** some people use double clicking feature on row, but it is a little bit tricky if you are new to ASP.Net

Comment: I disagree - with a hover highlight, clicking anywhere in the row is very user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You should add  between your GridView tags `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"`  like that;

```
  <asp:GridView AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        </asp:GridView>
```

And add these codes and change "ColumName"  with your SQL queries names.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    string MyId = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnName").ToString();
                    string Location = ResolveUrl("~/Your.aspx") + "?ColumName=" + MyId;
                    e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = string.Format("javascript:window.location='{0}';", Location);
                    e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "pointer";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two two ways to achieve this...
1.You can use selected index changed property of gridview. this is server side event.you can write 
server side code and redirect to student profile page.
2.Or you can use Jquery or javascript to add hyperlink to row.Just find out the gridview table and loop
 through in javascript and add onclick event to each row.Write a function for handling onclick event like
 this.
function rowclick(studentid)
{
window.location='studentprofile.aspx?studentid='+studentid;
}